# Block render until query has finished?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, next.js

I have a header component in my react app:

```
const SubmissionMeta = (props: { submissionId: string }) => {
    const { submissionId } = props
    let submission = useQuery(SUBMISSION_META, {
        ssr: true,
        variables: {
            id: submissionId
        },
        skip: submissionId === undefined
    })
    if (submission.loading || !submission.data) {
        return <></>
    }
    console.log(submission.data.submission.preview.url)

    const url = submission.data.submission.preview.url
    return <Head>
        <title>test title 123</title>
        <meta property="og:image" content={url} />
    </Head>
}
```

Is there a way to block rendering until useQuery has finished the query (i.e. while submission.loading wait)?

I'm running a vanilla nextjs react app.

My goal is to fetch some data from a remote graphql endpoint and use that data to populate the header.

I've tried to set up my apollo client to use ssr like so:

```
let client = new ApolloClient({
  ssrMode: true,
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

To clarify when I say 'block rendering' I mean hold off on SSR finalising until the server has the data to send the user so that the  tag will appear immediately with the loaded page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured this out by using [getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/fetching-data-for-pages) and returning the query from it, so the root component won't load until it has the query results as props passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work - try

```
return null
```

instead of

```
return <></>
```

The result should be pretty similar though

Comment: doesn't work, page renders then eventually the header meta data changeswhen the query finishes loading

Comment: @tweetypi is the submissionId prop changing? I see you skip if it's undefined..

Perhaps `if (!submissionId || submission.loading || !submission.data) {return null}`

Comment: Nope nothing to do with that as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries/#executing-a-query)

```
const SubmissionMeta = ({submissionId}) => {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(SUBMISSION_META, {
        ssr: true,
        variables: {
            id: submissionId
        },
        skip: submissionId === undefined
    })
    if (loading) return null;
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

    console.log(submission.data.submission.preview.url)
    const url = submission.data.submission.preview.url
    return (<Head>
        <title>test title 123</title>
        <meta property="og:image" content={url} />
    </Head>);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, page renders then eventually the header meta data changeswhen the query finishes loading